# Issue with destroying mutex in shared memory

Tags: posix, mutex, shared-memory, interprocess, reference-counting

I'm trying to implement a reference-counted shared memory using POSIX. That is, instead of manually calling `shm_unlink()`, the shared memory is destroyed (name unlinked) when the last outgoing reference to it is closed. I figured out that in order to achieve this, I need to put a mutex into the shared memory for synchronization purpose. But it seems that there is just no way to destroy the mutex properly. So, I'm wondering what are the potential effects if the mutex is not destroyed, but the shared memory it resides in is destroyed (i.e., with no outstanding reference and with name unlinked).